# Informatica PostgreSQL Uncached Lookup

Tags: postgresql, informatica, datadirect

I am using Informatica PowerCenter 10.4.1 with the DataDirect 7.1 PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver to do an uncached lookup to a table in PostgreSQL 14 database. The uncached lookup is using bind parameters in a SQL override. This is the SQL override in the lookup (this is a simplified version of a more complex query I am using for testing):

```
select
CASE
WHEN ?i_PARM?::integer = 0
THEN 'param = 0'
WHEN ?i_PARM?::integer = 1
THEN 'param = 1'
WHEN ?i_PARM?::integer is null
THEN 'param = null'
END AS PARM_VALUE
FROM public.dual--
```

The lookup works fine. It produces the correct result and the session log does not have any errors. The problem is the DBAs are seeing errors in the database log files like this:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "i_PARM$2" at character 23

STATEMENT: select
   CASE
   WHEN $i_PARM$2::integer = 0
   THEN 'param = 0'
   WHEN $i_PARM$4::integer = 1
   THEN 'param = 1'
   WHEN $i_PARM$6::integer is null
   THEN 'param = null'
   END AS PARM_VALUE
   FROM public.dual--
```

Is there anything I can do to make the database log error message go away? It seem strange to me the database is logging it as an error, but Informatica does not and also produces the correct results.

Comment: "from dual" Sure that isn't an Oracle response? Because Oracle won't understand the postgres cast shortcut `::` [use `cast($parm as integer)` instead]. And/or, why have two dollar symbols in a parameter name? remove the second "$" perhaps.

Comment: Yes, it is Postgres. We created a 'dual' table for some query compatibility. The first query is the correct syntaxt in Informatica for parameter subsitution. And I cannot remove the "$". I am not adding the '$'. That is happening at run time either by Informatica or the driver.

Comment: You can still try using cast instead of two colons. Have you tried? Otherwise I'm out of ideas based on the details available.

Comment: Maybe check the Informatica mapping configuration ensuring that the parameter bindings are correctly set up (including type) and that parameter values are being passed as expected. (Is it possible parameter values are not being passed?)

Comment: I checked the data type of the parameters in the mapping. They DID NOT match the cast data type. They were Double in the mapping, but Integer in the cast. I made them all Integer. Same failure.

I also tried cast($i_parm as integer) then cast(?i_parm? as integer). Both versions cause the session to fail. Somehow both of those cause Informatica to generate this query in the session log:

SELECT  is null
THEN 'param = null'
END  AS PARM_VALUE FROM public.dual-- 

And with cast like this, the database now logs two errors, one like the original error, and the other for the query above.

Comment: Sounds like something for informatica support to me. Doubt I can offer anything more on this.